# What is this type of hairstyle?

Tags: tropes

[image]

[image]
[image]

Its a kind of hairstyle that has two hair strands hanging down from the top of the head maybe at the center of it

Answer (score 14):

This is a sub-trope of [Anime Hair](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnimeHair), which is known as the [Hair Intakes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HairIntakes)

> A sub-trope of Anime Hair, this hairstyle resembles the hood scoops on a muscle car and also looks a bit like cat ears, allowing for the visual appeal of the Cat Girl in series that are too "realistic" to actually feature such a supernatural creature. Seems to be more common among females, though male examples are plentiful as well.
>
> Seems to be especially prevalent in Visual Novels.

Comment: This is literally what the Japanese call it, the ["Intake" hairstyle](https://web.archive.org/web/20181007222519/https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%86%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF_(%E9%AB%AA%E5%9E%8B)) ("inteku kamigata"), after the openings on certain car hoods that channel air into the engine. E.g., https://twitter.com/p__hone/status/689132473758793728